# Jmeter questions for newb

Tags: jmeter

So I need to peg a system with several thousand long polling requests.

I created a thread group with the requisite number of requests.  A few things confuse me.

(Im on a mac)

1. I run the jmeter.sh script to start the gui.  I cant run the test unless I run jmeter-server.  Without it I get a "cannot connect to 127.0.0.1..." message.  The docs don't mention needing to start this script up.
2. In the jmeter.sh script I set the max memory to `export JVM_ARGS="-Xms4096m -Xmx4096m"`. Nonetheless, whenever I start running the test I *immediately* see

`Uncaught Exception java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread. See log file for details.`

3. I tried running my test headless and it didn't get better; it gets thru roughly 2k requests before just stopping.  I was hoping for about 40-50k threads (i.e. requests).  I cant reuse threads (that I know of) as this long polling so the requests block until something causes them to release.

Any advice? Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't make sense. you shouldn't need to run jmeter-server unless you have a need to run meter in server mode, say with remote engines.

Depending on the version of java you are running you are likely exceeding the memory space available to the JVM used by jmeter. Not sure why you are allocating 4 GB. You should be fine with 512M or perhaps 1024M. I have found that Jmeter can tend to leak over time anyway.

Your headless test should give you an indication that you are either running out of memory or thread space with Jmeter or perhaps, and more likely, you are overburdening your server, probably exhausting the thread pool.

First thing I would do is change the memory to something more conservative, say -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m. Also, 40-50k requests is not 40-50k threads. They are concepts that work with each other but are not necessarily the same thing. So perhaps you are setting something up in Jmeter destined to fail by creating too many concurrent threads.

Comment: i hear you. I am on a mac and never did an install; Im running straight from the unzipped download -- is that ok?  I only upped the memory after it fails -- I get the out of memory error *immediately*.   Also,  why does it error immediately  when I try to run from the GUI without the server running?  Finally, im testing long polling, so the requests don't return till I do something to cause them too -- so I think it needs to be 1 request/thread (but could be wrong)

Comment: Hi. I would suggest using something like Homebrew to install meter on the Mac. I use Homebrew for everything they have a package for. Then it is a simple brew install meter command.

The Jmeter script is looking for a response from your application locally on startup. So if your app is running on port 8080 it would look to something like http://localhost:8080/myApp. localhost equates to 127.0.0.1 which is the loopback address for your machine; a virtual interface.

As for the long polling you need to simulate this in the test, add a delay in the thread group that simulates your response.

Comment: To follow my last comment, make sure your app is running on localhost and that you don't have any HTTP request settings that contradict your http request defaults (if you use them).

Comment: Also, I should have mentioned as recommended by other watching this thread that a thread is equivalent to a user i.e. 1 thread = 1 user, but 1 user can create "n" number of request. This is an important concept. You have to determine if your use case requires this sort of model and alter your test accordingly as it will affect resource usage.

Comment: Oops meant: brew install jmeter